# How to smoothly move from one view to another with cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to be able to smoothly move from one view of a given graph to another, so that the graph gradually moves from its original position and zoom level to the destination defined in the second view, like in an animation.

How can I do that with cytoscape.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`cy.animate()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.animate) or [`cy.animation()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.animation) to animate the viewport.  You can specify easing and the duration to make the animation flow how you like.